# extend numpy to unknown numbers

Tags: python, numpy

I want to make 3-d numpy like
(12,2,3)

But in this case 12 is unknown.

What I wan to do is like this below, (but this code is not correct)

```
final_results = np.zeros(*,2,3)
for i in range(16):
  final_results.append(getMatrix()) #getMatrix() returns the  (2,3) numpy
```

Each time getMatrix returns the (2,3) array.

So final_results.shape should change like this in the loop.

(1,2,3) -> (2,2,3) ->(3,2,3)-> (4,2,3) -> (5,2,3)

How can I do this??

Comment: Does `numpy.zeros_like()` solve your problem?

Comment: Also, this question is quite difficult to understand. I suggest trying to clarify what you want.

Comment: Updated my answer based on your edit, do check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### EDIT:

Based on your updated answer, this is how you would use your `np.stack` -

```
#Function returns (2,3) matrix each time its called
def getMatrix():
    return np.random.random((2,3))

#Collect all the (2,3) matrices in a list
iterate_matrices = [getMatrix() for i in range(5)]

#Stack them into a single array
output = np.stack(iterate_matrices)
output.shape
```

```
(5, 2, 3)
```

Comment: `np.stack` works well. it's what I wanted to do.My first question is too clumsy to understand. thank you very much.